# Customize updated|timesince in a django template

Tags: python, html, django

I've a django template which displays the last time an element was updated in a database like this:

```
<small>updated {{ updated|timesince }} ago</small>
```

where `updated` is the timestamp of the last update of that element.

I, however, don't like thw way it is displaying this information. For example if i's just updated it sais: 'updated 0 minutes ago' which looks kinda wierd. I would like it to say something like: 'updated just now'

So I wrote this piece of code to try to make that happen:

```
{% if is_updated%}
     {% if updated|timesince == '0 minutes' %}
         <small>updated just now </small>
     {% else %}
         <small>updated {{ updated|timesince }} ago</small>
     {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

here `is_updated` is a context variable set like this:

```
if element.updated != element.uploaded:
    is_updated = True
```

however it's always showing me 'updated X minutes ago' even if the element hasn't been updated. What could I be doing wrong?

Model for the element:

```
title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
identifier  = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
category    = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="uncategorized")
description_short = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="none")
description = models.TextField(default="none")
uploaded    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
time        = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if an instance is only once created and never touched again, the two `auto_add` and `auto_add_now` `DateTimeFields` can hold slightly different timestamps. If you check it in the shell, you will see sth like:

```
>>> element.uploaded
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 14, 7, 37, 542192, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> element.updated
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 14, 7, 37, 542213, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

You notice the difference in the microseconds. You should check their equality with a little epsilon:

```
if (element.updated - element.uploaded).microseconds > 500:
    is_updated = True
```

`timesince` does not support time deltas under a minute. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince):

> Minutes is the smallest unit used, and “0 minutes” will be returned for any date that is in the future relative to the comparison point.

All you can do is feed the extra information into the context:

```
# view
recent = (element.updated - element.uploaded).seconds < 60

# template
{% if recent %}
     <small>updated just now </small>
 {% else %}
     <small>updated {{ updated|timesince }} ago</small>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: This works for the is_updated part... But it still displayes 'updated 0 minutes ago' whenever the time between last update and now is less than 1 minute... How could I go aboutdoingthat?

Comment: @BRHSM I added some suggestions for that to my answer.